# Create 4 scatter subplots from one dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, subplot

I have database that contains observations and then it has for each one PCA analysis- PCA 1 and PCA 2, that were calculated for different dates:
[image]

**My goal:
create 4 scatter subplots, based on those dates,and to color them in different colors, based on column "line_leg".**

What I have done so far:

Created  4 scatter subplotplots -

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2,figsize=(16, 10))
```

[image]

and tried to plot the ax[0][0] +color it this way:

```
targets = ['100 D','100 C','70 D','70 C','40 D', '40 C']
colors = ['tab:blue','tab:green','tab:purple','tab:cyan','tab:red','tab:orange']
#colors = ['lawngreen','royalblue','tab:green','midnightblue','tab:red','tab:orange']
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    #goes to line. and check of 1,2,3,4,5,6 are true or false, 6 times total, and if true gives the color.
    indicesToKeep = df_PCA_all['line_leg'] == target
    ax[0][0].scatter(df_PCA_all.iloc[:,3:5].loc[indicesToKeep, 'PCA1_19']
               , df_PCA_all.iloc[:,3:5].loc[indicesToKeep, 'PCA2_19']
               , c = color
               , s = 100
               , label=target)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
```

But I got error:

> TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable

**My end goal is to have those 4 figures plot with  the data from the  df,  each figure shows different date (19,21,28,03), and colored according to the value of line_leg.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You array of Axes is calles `axes`, not `ax`. You should call `axes[0,0].scatter(...)`